# Theorem environment without "Theorem" at the beginning

Tags: theorems

I am writing a appendix for my thesis, where I want to put the most relevant results that I cite from various sources. I want to do this because I would like to keep everything as self-contained as possible, so that a possible reader can read the main needed results on the appendix without searching lots of textbooks and articles.

Now, many of these results are well known (for example, the Implicit function theorem), while others are just useful propositions or corollaries that maybe are well known but don't have a "proper name".

While "Theorem 1.1 Implicit function theorem [1]" is acceptable ([1] would be the reference in bibliography), I refuse to write something like "Theorem 1.2 Corollary 3.2 [2]", meaning that I refer to the Corollary 3.2 of [2]. How can I get into the "theorem environment" without triggering the automatic "Theorem x.x" at the beginning?

Comment: Do you want to suppress BOTH the theorem name AND the theorem numbering? Also, are you using `amsthm` or `ntheorem` in your document? Or are you creating theorem environments using another package?

Comment: I want to suppress both. Ideally it should be just a list of results taken from various sources. I am using amsthm

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own theorem style that prints ONLY the notes field and nothing else. (Note that you shouldn't try to `\label` and `\ref` these theorems...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{bfnoteonly}%
{}{}%
{\itshape}{}%
{\bfseries}{.}%
{ }%
{\thmnote{#3}}

\theoremstyle{bfnoteonly}
\newtheorem*{extthm}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{extthm}[Implicit Function Theorem]
        Give a $C^1$ function $f$.
\end{extthm}

\begin{extthm}[Morse Lemma]
        Given a manifold $M$.
\end{extthm}
\end{document}
```

You can see the `amsthm` documentation, section 4, for details on how to use the `\newtheoremstyle` command to define new theorem styles.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestion!